# The import android.support.test can not be resolved in revision 22

Tags: android, testing, android-support-library, android-uiautomator

I am trying to use the support library for testing in Android. However, when I try to import

```
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
```

as it is described [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#features) it says

```
The import android.support.test can not be resolved
```

I want to use revision 22 as I want to use the new features presented for UiAutomator.

**There is no support\test folder in sources**

I was digging around the sdk folder and I've notice that even though the path sources\android-21\android\support\test exists, sources\android-22\android\support has no test folder (there is a tests one but only with GrantActivity.java inside).

Did I forget to import any jars? (I tried importing support-annotations, and support-v4 but it's the same result).

Am I doing something wrong? I hope so and that you guys can help me figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

*Note: I have downloaded the Android Support Repository and Library, I have all the packages from API 22 and I have Tools, Platform-Tools and Build-Tools up to date.*

(I don't think it matters but I'm using Eclipse Kepler in Windows 7)

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, not Android Studio.

Comment: Google dropped support for Eclipse a long time ago. Id suggest making the switch.

Comment: But you think the problem may stand there? I'm just using Eclipse because I'm doing this as part of another Java project and Android Studio can't be used for "normal" Java projects. I can do each project in a different IDE but I didn't see the need.

Do you think that might help?

Comment: What? Android Studio is based off Intellij, you can easily add a Java based module. This is the whole point of Android Studio: It is a stream-lined build system.

Comment: It is based on IntelliJ but it does not provide everything IntelliJ does. Otherwise noone would pay for IntelliJ. At least that was what I understood for lokking around and downloading it. I may be wrong. But anyway do you think it would help in my problem?

Comment: IntelliJ is free. If you were using Android Studio, all you would have to do is add `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'`.https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions

Comment: I second the suggestion to switch to Android Studio. It's probably not worth convoluting your build process if it's not going to pay dividends in the future; you'll likely find yourself following the same procedure to get other new features functioning correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't really supported, but since you're using Eclipse, you'll need to import the jar manually. The Android Support Repository gets downloaded to `<SDK_DIR>/extras/android/m2repository`. The class you want is part of the testing-support-lib, which is in the repository under `com/android/support/test/testing-support-lib/0.1`

Android uses [.aar files](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) for libraries, and the testing-support-lib is published as an aar. This format isn't supported by Ant, but if you unzip the testing-support-lib-0.1.aar file, it contains a classes.jar file that you can import.

As mentioned in the comments, you really should make the switch to Android Studio and use Gradle going forward so that you don't have to jump through these hoops.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will make the switch to Android Studio but right now you were a life saver :)